# How to deploy functions server for apiai-facts-about-google-nodejs Actions example

Tags: google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google

I'm following the instructions for the [Facts About Google](https://github.com/actions-on-google/apiai-facts-about-google-nodejs) example and I can't seem to perform the step in the README.md:

> Deploy the fulfillment webhook to your preferred hosting environment
>   (we recommend Google Cloud Functions).

I am trying to start the functions server:

```
$ functions deploy factsAboutGoogle --trigger-http
functions deploy <functionName> <modulePath>

Options:
  --host, -h          The emulator's host.                                                                      [string]
  --port, -p          The emulator's port.                                                                      [number]
  --help              Show help                                                                                [boolean]
  --version           Show version number                                                                      [boolean]
  --trigger-http, -t  Deploys the function as an HTTP function.

Not enough non-option arguments: got 1, need at least 2
```

I have also tried using `npm start` but I get the same issue. I don't know what the functionName or modulePath should be.

Comment: Try `functions deploy factsAboutGoogle . --trigger-http` (note the `.`) from the same directory that has the `index.js` file. `functionName` should be the name of the function in the code to run and `modulePath` should be the directory the module/package/set of code files are in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following and just saw that abraham had the same idea. This worked for me:

```
functions deploy factsAboutGoogle ./ --trigger-http
```

Comment: I have no idea why this works - but it does. Thanks!